# How can i Redirect Chrome/Firefox Extension with same opened tab if we click on same URL again?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to create Firefox extension to redirect to new tab when clicked on any URL or button and also to **Redirect with same opened tab if we click on same URL again**

**Example:** If i click on Link tag, its opens to new tab using `window.open('https://example.com', 'child-window');`

I want to redirect to the same tab if already have open previously else it should open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

U can create your Own window using window.open and check using if and else

```
<body>

<button onclick="openRequestedPopup('https://stackoverflow.com/')">Home</button>

<button onclick="openRequestedPopup('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript')">Your Question </button>

 <script>
var pre = '';
function openRequestedPopup(url) {
    if (pre !== url) {
        myWindow = window.open(url, "Open", 'left=100,top=100,width=320,height=320');
        pre = url
    }
    else if (myWindow.closed) {
        pre = ''
        openRequestedPopup(url)

    }
    else {
        myWindow.focus();
    }
}
  </script>
</body>
```